# Is the curl of matrix times gradient equal to zero?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

We know that if $u$ is a smooth function, $\nabla \times (\nabla u) = 0$.

If $M$ is a positive-definite, invertible matrix, is there a chance that $\nabla \times (M\nabla u)$ is also zero?

The vector identities I found don't seem to cover this case so I can't expand it.

Comment: My guess is that if the transformation shears, then no. As a counterexample take the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 &0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\\ \end{pmatrix}$$But if it is a pure rotation and a stretch like complex numbers, then maybe.

Comment: A sufficient condition for the curl to vanish is for the quantity $\alpha_{ijs}:= \epsilon_{ijk}M_{ks}$ (all indices in $\{1,2,3\}$, and summation convention used) to be such that for all $i$, $\alpha_{ijs} = -\alpha_{isj}$ (i.e it has to be skew symmetric in the last two indices). This is because the $i^{th}$ component of $\nabla \times (M\nabla u)$ is $\epsilon_{ijk}M_{ks}\partial_j\partial_su = \alpha_{ijs}\partial_j\partial_su$. So, if $\alpha$ is skew-symmetric in the $j,s$ indices, then since $\partial_j\partial_s= \partial_s\partial_j$, it follows that the result will be $0$.

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo, you can post as answer if you like